# How to detect force delete in model event

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have set up a model event to check when an image is deleted and delete the related image_size model entries. However image uses soft deletes so if it is being soft deleted then I want to soft delete the image_size records but if the image is being hard deleted using forceDelete then I want to hard delete the image_size records. Is there a way to detect what type of delete it is and act accordingly. Here is what I have so far in my Image model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Image extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['url', 'thumb_url', 'filename'];

    /**
     * Relationship to image sizes
     */
    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image_size');
    }

    /**
    * Model events
    */
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($image) { // before delete() method call this
             $image->sizes()->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If i remember correctly you have a property on the `$image` object called `forceDeleting`.

```
static::deleting(function($image) { 
    if($image->forceDeleting){
        //do in case of force delete
    } else {
        //do in case of soft delete
    }
});
```

However i think last time i did this was in a few versions back, so not sure if it still works.

Comment: It looks like this is now `$image->isForceDeleting()`

Answer (score 5):

Now `forceDeleting` is protected (you can't access to value). You need use
`$image->isForceDeleting()`

When you work with **Observers** (recommended on Laravel >5.5).

```
class Image extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    /* ... */

    protected static function boot(): void
    {
        parent::boot();
        parent::observe(ImageObserver::class);
    }
}

class ImageObserver
{
    public function deleting($image): void
    {
        if ($image->isForceDeleting()) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As of Laravel 5.6, the SoftDeletes trait now fires a `forceDeleted` model event.